# Buttons become mis-aligned when window is resized

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I'm designing my interface in Interface Builder (using Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard), and PERFECTLY aligning two elements (two `NSButton`s, bordered), one below the other.

The thing is that when the window is resizing, at some points, the elements seem misaligned (by 1 pixel or so), while at some other, they're still perfectly aligned.

---

Here's a (zoomed) example of what I mean:

**Aligned**

[image]

**Mis-Aligned**

[image]

---

And here are my resizing settings (for the upper `NSButton`):

[image]

And for the container (of my upper `NSButton`):

[image]

---

I know I'm probably getting a bit too crazy about such a tiny issue, but I definitely need to resolve it.

So, why is that happening? What should I do in order to resolve it?

Comment: Definitely not crazy; this is the kind of detail that one _should_ be paying attention to.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar I feel quite better now... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both buttons in the same container?

Do they have the same size & alignment settings?

Below the autosizing widgets in the inspector, there's a set of alignment buttons.  Try selecting both buttons and clicking the left-side alignment button.  (See if that makes the other side mis-align.) Below that are placement icons - verify both buttons have same settings there.

Type in values for W & H so both buttons are the exact same (even if the boxes already show the same, type over it to be sure). Also type in X & Y so they're same (except for vertical offset).

Personally, having the center scaling set (last image, double-ended horizontal arrow) seems odd when it's only anchored on one side.  That might have a strange effect. On the other hand, you have both vertical anchors set but not the vertical scaling.

If all else fails, you could try (save original version first) delete the second button, copy the first and position the copy below it.